# Can I get 18V pulses from a USB 2.0 port?

Tags: usb

What do I need in order to run a 12mW/28mA @18V device with square waves between 0 and 18V, using a USB 2.0 port and control the USB output w/ Python? It's a PC.

Comment: Even though you could do it using (a lot of) additional hardware, it isn’t feasible.

Comment: Since you only need 12mW, you could, in theory, get by using a boost converter. This is then in the realm of electronics design and has little to do with the source being USB/PC.

Comment: @Journeman Geek, how it is off-topic? The OP has a PC running Python. How is not a computer software? He needs to make 18V pulses using USB port. He asks "how". How it is not about computer hardware? The spectrum of answers suggests a serious confusion about how a PC can (or can't) control external electronics.

Comment: @AliChen, I suspect the issue is that this gets into design of an electronic device that's controlled by the PC.  Once you get outside of using standard interfaces for standard purposes, you're getting out of scope for the site.  "What do I need in order to run a 12mW/28mA @ 18V device with square waves between 0 and 18V, using a USB 2.0 port" is an electronics design question, and "control the USB output w/ Python" is a programming question.

Comment: @fixer1234, are you saying that the question should be split in two, (1) How do I control a GPIO over USB port using Python, and (2) How do I generate 18V pulses from a 5V power rail using 3.3V GPIO pin? The second question would belong to EE site, I agree, but wouldn't the first part still be within the scope of "superuser"?

Comment: @AliChen, my guess would be SO would be the appropriate place for that.

Comment: @fixer1234, I am still struggling to understand the reason for such nit-picking policy. The question is very reasonable as compared to dozens of other totally idiotic and ignorant questions. The USB tag is stagnant, ~3 question per day, there is no reason to limit anything. Also, why the question  was closed based on opinion of one person?

Comment: @AliChen, this discussion might be better on Meta, but basically, programming questions are off-topic here.  There are a few exceptions, like VBA, batch files and shell scripts, probably because they can be so integral to on-topic questions.  re: opinion of one person: moderators are guardians of the site, with the knowledge, responsibility, and authority appertaining thereto.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

If the device takes 18V at 28mA, it is just 500mW. It should be no problem for any USB 5V port. To accomplish the task you would need:

1. A USB device with at least one GPIO. This one would do [FTDI](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2264).
2. Design/buy a boost converter circuit (add-on board) from 5V to 18V;
3. Have a transistor to drive 18V pulses to your "18V device" using the GPIO as control for the transistor. Any BJT or FET will do. Read the Adafruit board documents on how to control the GPIO via Python.
4. Patience and luck (if your square wave needs to be in low-kHz range).

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to not worry about powering up the device (i.e. using an **external**, independent power supply) and using a USB controlled switch.

This has the advantage of simplicity, electric decoupling (you don't want to fry your PC attempting to supply power, even if it's not so much power) and device stability, for you would keep the device always "running" and just [modulate its output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246077/controlling-simple-relay-switch-via-usb). For example you can use a USB-to-RS232 to get a useable signal.

Otherwise, you can power the device from a step-up DC-DC converter (5 to 18V). You can find [ready-made 12V models](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/5pcs-dc-dc-boost-converter-3-3V-3-7V-4-5V-5V-6V-to-12V-Step/32324973536.html) easily enough; I found once a 24V 50mW one, in a kit. Or you can build one yourself or have someone build you one from schematics you can Google. Not really something I'd recommend, though. Consider that with most step-up circuits out there, the output voltage might need additional regulation to be compatible with your device, as you get considerable rippling.

You might discover that you aren't able to both power up the device and control it from the same USB port, and you need two USB ports. With most USB chips, if you attach a dumb load you get a "default" current which is not the maximum the port can supply (it should still be enough, but *check*), for chip self-protection reasons. But to have your device transmit the necessary "Send more current, I'm OK with that" signals, you would need more hardware still. What I suspect is that you might find that the complication of doing *that* is actually more than simply getting an independent power supply.

Answer (score 0):

According to [USB Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Power) - USB 2.0 is not able to power 18V. Maximum of 5V and 5A for battery charging.

USB with Power Delivery (Credit to Daniel B) is able to provide up to 20V power, so that should be your best bet for trying that kind of power output.

Reference from wikipedia:

- Power Delivery micro-format
- Power Delivery standard format or Type-C

Comment: USB-C is but a form factor. What you’re referring to is USB Power Delivery. It requires special cables and awareness on both ends of the connection.

Comment: @DanielB  Ah thanks for the correction :) I did misread the wiki page and seeing the "type-C" referred there so I thought it was normal USB-C (like the port I've seen on the MacBook) - but didn't realize it was more special than that.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve this result with a external power source along with a transistor that is switched by signals coming from the USB cable. I wouldn't recommend trying to use a step-up regulator with the 5 Volts that a USB cable gives out.

But, AFAIK there is no real way to send a square wave via pure USB from a computer. What you could try to do is hook up a USB to Serial cable and send it ASCII U characters, you'll get a square wave at frequency 1/2 the rate at which you send them.

You could also go the easy route and use an Arduino or another small micro controller to generate the clock for the waves (This is a great option if you are going to have a variable frequency).